# What should I consider when setting up photo sessions at 3rd party location?

Tags: portrait, business, contracts, locations

Now that fall is here, I am considering approaching a local farm/apple orchard/pumpkin patch to set up a day of portrait sessions -- where families can come to the farm for a specific time frame and get portraits taken in the pumpkin patch/picturesque orchards, etc.

Any aspects I should consider when approaching the farm to see if they would be interested -- such as, should I expect to pay a fee for this, or would places consider this "publicity", etc... has anyone done this kind of thing, and if so, do you have any tips/things to consider?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could try selling this to them as something they can add to their marketing. After all it adds to the attraction of their venue if this service is on offer. If this isn't enough for them then try sweetening the deal with a small cut of the profits that way you only pay out if you make money. I have never done this myself but know others that have and its usually a case of making them aware of the mutual benefits that your being there will bring. Also make sure you have adequate public liability insurance in case anything goes wrong, something as simple as a child running into a light stand could ruin your whole day without it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to consider the insurance aspects as well, I know it's boring but if someone gets injured and tries to go down the 'where there's a blame there's a claim' route it's good to know you're legally safe.

I do however know people who've done location shoots in places ranging from mansions to aircraft museums, the thing you'll generally find is if they're not already getting used they're probably flattered you've asked and happy to get some marketing material, if they are used by photographers and film crews they'll have standard rates set up. Just try ringing round a few prospective places and see what responses you get.

Answer (score 0):

#### Re. Fees

First, work out what you would be prepared to pay if they did ask for a fee.  Then you know when to walk away if they ask for too much.

Having said that, always ask to do it for free first.
Many people will be flattered just to be asked.  Of course, since you're there anyway, and the film is free, you could offer to do some complimentary publicity shots / portraits / etc. for them.

Get them (the location owners) to sign a release for the location.

(Also get the clients to sign releases).

It is your responsibility to ensure that you have all the required insurance in place and that you meet all necessary legal requirements.  You need to talk you your own laywer about this, and hopefully you have a good insurance agent too.